# How to get nested result format in aggregate query in Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection need to `$graphLookup`  but I am confused on how to implement it in aggregate framework. My idea is query multiple levels down until find no more children. How can I query with $graphLookup to make a nested result?

Comment Model:

```
const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        postId: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            index: true,
        },
        replyTo: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: false,
            index: true,
        },
        userId: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users',
            required: true,
            index: true,
        },
        commentDetail: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        }
    }
)
```

Documents data in Comment collection:

```
{ 
   _id: 1,
   postId: "649098feb38c50b3640222fb", 
   replyTo: null, 
   userId: "64909accb38c50b364022302", 
   commentDetail: 'thanks for the great post!' 
}

{ 
   _id: 2,
   postId: "649098feb38c50b3640222fb", 
   replyTo: 1, 
   userId: "6490991eb38c50b3640222fe", 
   commentDetail: 'hehe, thanks!' 
}

{ 
   _id: 3,
   postId: "649098feb38c50b3640222fb", 
   replyTo: 1, 
   userId: "6490991eb38c50b3640222fe", 
   commentDetail: 'hope you like it!' 
}
```

My expected result I want to get:

```
  [
     { 
       _id: 1,
       postId: "649098feb38c50b3640222fb", 
       userId: "64909accb38c50b364022302", 
       commentDetail: 'thanks for the great post!',
       reply: [
          { 
            _id: 2,
            postId: "649098feb38c50b3640222fb", 
            userId: "6490991eb38c50b3640222fe", 
            commentDetail: 'hehe, thanks!',
            reply: [] 
          },
          { 
            _id: 3,
            postId: "649098feb38c50b3640222fb", 
            userId: "6490991eb38c50b3640222fe", 
            commentDetail: 'hope you like it!',
            reply: []  
          }               
       ]
     },
     ... 
  ]
```

Comment: somehting like this? https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZG1SSTaY4Lx

Comment: @cmgchess Thanks! I tried your way in this playground but it's only recursive 1 level, I want to get the results with multiple levels down until find no more children.

Comment: I see can you give a multi nested example